# Set sessionStorage, change image

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I just wish that based on the sessionstorage I set, the image would change ... sessionstorage is set correctly, but the image will not change...

what did I miss?

```js
function caption_on_off() {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("caption_on_off") == 'off'){
        sessionStorage.setItem("caption_on_off", 'on');
       }else{
        sessionStorage.setItem("caption_on_off", 'off');
    }
}

function change_caption_img(){
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("caption_on_off") == 'off'){
        document.getElementById('caption_on_off_img').src = 'images/on.png';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('caption_on_off_img').src = 'images/off.png';
    }
}
change_caption_img();
```

```html
<div id="gallery_div_caption" onclick="Hide('gallery_div_caption'); caption_on_off();"><img id="caption_on_off_img" src="images/off.png"></div>
```

I thought of doing it separately because the page is a php page, and is reloaded with new variables, new mysql queries etc., but I need the page to remember which image it should load based on the sessionstorage status even after being reloaded.

If it was all php I would save in a coockie and read it in php, can I read a sessionstorage via php?

---------------------update----------------------

I was thinking of adding a variable to my ajax url as suggested by M1K1O, maybe the simplest way, but it's a mess because it is compiled via php and then added to the html text, using all possible quotes...
how do I add it now sessionstorage here?

```
$link_onclick .= "javascript:AjaxPhp('img_div', 'gallery_img.php', '?img_title=".clean_url($row_news['id_news']."-".$row_news['titolo'])."&amp;img_title_it=".clean_url($row_news['id_news']."-".$row_news['titolo_it'])."&amp;img_n=".$g."&amp;refer=".$row_news['refer']."&amp;link_out=".$link_out."&amp;captions_exist=".$captions_exist."&amp;caption_on_off= ... session storage here...'); Show('gallery_div'); return(false);";
```

Comment: your change_caption_img() function needs to be called in every route change(). Can you log and see if it is getting called each time you go to that page?

Comment: sessionstorage is in browser, never sent to server. so no, PHP can't read it unless you explicitly send it via ajax.

Comment: it's a bit of a mess, because the php page that must recognize the image is reloaded via ajax ... but I put the change_caption_img () function at the beginning of the php script inside the script that is reloaded ... so I thought would have read and understood every time, but it seems not ...

Comment: is that script before HTML? then is DOM not loaded yet.

Comment: maybe yes, also because the first function I have to put in the html page that is loaded by the browser, not in the script loaded via ajax, otherwise it doesn't work ...

Comment: any JS console errors? like `Cannot set property 'src' of null`?

Comment: nothing... just it doesn't work...

Comment: You have to run `caption_on_off` twice in order to change the sessionStorage item to 'on'. The first time it hits that `if` condition, it's null, so it sets the value to 'off'. On the second click, the value is 'off', so it will be set to 'on'. Also, you'd have to call `change_caption_img` after setting the value in sessionStorage.

Comment: try IIFE rather than calling it like change_caption_img();

Comment: @SunilLama what difference would it make?

Comment: @alebal `...&amp;caption_on_off='+sessionStorage.getItem("caption_on_off"))...` it's JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: Work well now... thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function and logic is fine but it is getting called only once with your syntax. Either wrap it in document ready or document load or I would suggest using IIFE, if you want your function to be called in every page reload as follows:

```
(function change_caption_img(){
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("caption_on_off") == 'off'){
        document.getElementById('caption_on_off_img').src = 'images/on.png';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('caption_on_off_img').src = 'images/off.png';
    }
})();
```

Comment: @alebal, can you see if the function is getting called each time you are going to that page?

Comment: Can you post the part of ajax?